# My Graphic Card on Macbook Pro 2020 doesnt work correctly

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics

This is my Macbook:

[image]

And when I open google maps, 3d view, then my fan starts working very loud. And this is how it looks:

Is everything ok with this? Is my graphic card working fine?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having the fan ramp up while performing complex graphical work is not unexpected.

As for the picture anomaly: does this occur 'everywhere' in Google Maps, or just one location?

If there's no similar problem when performing any other graphically intensive task, then I would not point at the graphics hardware as the source of the problem.

Comment: This occur everywhere. It takes a second but appears everywhere...

Comment: What about any other app? I'd still be more inclined to think "software glitch" than "hardware problem".

Comment: How can I check other apps? Is there any tool for this? For me everything else works...

Comment: Check by looking at them! If no other app has a problem, then it's probably a bug in Google Maps. Are you up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, I use Safari the latest version.